# How to use a partial view in Rails to hit multiple pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index and show that both contain social media sharing and it looks something like this:

```
 <% @books.drop(1).each_slice(2) do |bookish| %>
   <div class="row">
     <% bookish.each do |book|%>
       <div class="fb-share-button" id="fbid>
         <div data-href="url.com/<%= book.book_name %>" data-layout="button" data-size="small">
           <a class="share-link" target="_blank" href="facebook.com/<%=book.book_description%>">
```

This works for both the index and the show but since I'm repeating the same code in multiple locations I'd rather just use a partial view. So when I move that code into a partial and replace it with this:

```
<% render partial: '/books/book' %>
```

I end up getting undefined method for book_name. And looking in my terminal it's sharing

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'book_name' for nil:NilClass)
```

Did I miss needing to add something to my partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `locals`:

```
<% render partial: '/books/book', locals: { book: book } %>
```

Comment: Tried that along with with <% render partial: '/books/book', locals: { book: @book } %>. Didn't like that unfortunately. Got undefined local variable or method 'book'. Also tried <% render partial: '/books/book' => 'book" %> with a different outcome that didn't work. Even tried <% render partial: '/books/book', book: book %> and same issue.

Comment: Yeah I was also had render partial at another section of the page that was throwing the error. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

#### 1) with keys `partial, locals`

```
<% render partial: '/books/book', locals: { book: book } %>
```

#### 2) without keys `partial, locals`

```
<% render '/books/book', book: book %>
```

Method `render` calls method `_normalize_args` inside so if you pass arguments using the second approach it will automatically detect type of what you want to render. [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-_normalize_args)